# JavaScript in HTML/Angular doesn't toggle tabs

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to design a Login/Sign Up form with 2 tabs to change between. this code works perfectly on CodePen, However it does not work when run locally via angular server. It doesnt change tabs when clicking on Login.

```
   <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function(e) 
      {
      var $this = $(this),
          label = $this.prev('label');
        if (e.type === 'keyup') {
          if ($this.val() === '') {
              label.removeClass('active highlight');
            } else {
              label.addClass('active highlight');
            }
        } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
          if( $this.val() === '' ) {
            label.removeClass('active highlight');
          } else {
            label.removeClass('highlight');
          }
        } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

          if( $this.val() === '' ) {
            label.removeClass('highlight');
          }
          else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
            label.addClass('highlight');
          }
        }

    });

    $('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

      target = $(this).attr('href');

      $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();

      $(target).fadeIn(600);

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
       .....
</body>
```

Comment: All I see is jQuery here. Are you building an Angular app or what? If so, this is not how it should be done.

Comment: @Dino, the rest is html css and it works fine. the only problem is the toggling part between 2 tabs that this doesnt do it but it works online. the other angular attributes are ok

Comment: Why would you not use Angular to do this? This makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to solve your problem:

1. use [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) instead
2. toggle your views using [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)
3. Install jQuery by `npm install jquery` and add it to your angular.json like below

   ```
   "scripts": [
     "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   ]
   ```

   > Note that you have to import jquery inside your component, too, using: `import * as $ from 'jquery';`
   >
   > But you should avoid using jQuery in an Angular app, because Angular has its own methods for many kinds of jQuerys stuff built in. Furthermore if you manipulate the DOM using jQuery, you'll have to force angular to detect changes as angular does not pick up the changes automatically.